# Return full entries or only id and title per entry from REST /entries endpoint?

Tags: rest

I have the following REST API:

- GET /notes
- GET /notes/:id

```
note 
{
   id, title, body 
}
```

Would it be acceptable to return only `{id, title}` from `/notes` endpoint? I don't want to drag note bodies along when user requests note list. I would rather return full note `{id, title, body}` when user makes a choice and requests for a concrete note using `/notes/id` endpoint.

Probably should introduce `/note_list` endpoint for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that it is RESTful to return full resources when using `/notes` endpoint  but it seems strange to me. Why would anyone ever need whole table data? In 99 percents you need just referential data (id and name) when requesting the list of entries.

Anyway, after some research I found the following options:

1. Partial response in style of [google api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial-response)
2. Introduce a special parameter to `/notes` endpoint to mark that the response will be partial, for example `/notes/header`

Approach 1 is probably an overkill for my specialized api, I might go with approach 2.